# Filtering results by selected option on drop down menu

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter by date using a drop down menu of dates.  The date comparison is working and I can use the data structure below to filter when checkboxes are being used.  Can't seem to get this working by drop down menu though.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this?  I'm thinking the problem is relating to the `model` in some way but I'm not sure what I need to do to sort it.

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
 {name: "1/2/2015", selected: true,  value: Date {Sun Feb 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}},
 {name: "8/2/2015", selected: true,  value: Date {Sun Feb 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}}
]
```

Here's my code to create the html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedFilterOption" class="dropdown-select" ng-options="cruiseDepDate.value as cruiseDepDate.name for cruiseDepDate in cruiseDepDates">
   <option value="{{cruiseDepDate.value}}">{{cruiseDepDate.name}}</option>
</select>
```

my filter code:

```
.filter('cruiseDateFilter', function(){
   return function(cruiseResults, cruiseDepDates){
     filteredResults = []

        for(var i=0; i<cruiseResults.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<cruiseDepDates.length; j++){
                if(cruiseResults[i].DepartureDate.toString() === cruiseDepDates[j].value.toString()){
                    filteredResults.push(cruiseResults[i])
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredResults;
   }
})
```

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9K2eiLuMkqAx73w3A2F9?p=preview) showing roughly want I want to achieve.  I want to filter the results based on the selected option on the drop down list.  I need the option list to show a formatted date but I need to filter on another value, in the plunkr example this is an unformatted date string.

Thank you in advance for any help with this :)

Comment: could you provide a plunkr perhaps?

Comment: I've added a plunkr example .... it hopefully shows roughly what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is a working solution for your problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FjcyfgwjbCbaKta71uYv?p=preview

```
app.filter('cruiseDateFilter', function(){
    return function(cruiseResults, someOtherDates){
        return cruiseResults.filter(function(item) {
            for(var i=0; i<someOtherDates.length; i++){
                if(someOtherDates[i].value.toString() === item.value.toString()) return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    };
});
```

and here is html part, where the filter is being called in:
`ng-options="cruiseDepDate.value as cruiseDepDate.name for cruiseDepDate in cruiseDepDates | cruiseDateFilter:otherDates"`

Comment: I don't think that's quite it.  I need to filter the `cruiseResults` based on the option in the list selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here a separate directive written for solving the drop down issue in regard to select option, you can refer the below link.

https://angularjsbrain.wordpress.com/fast-prototyping-with-angularjs/dependency-injection-ajax-support/